# bagoffeatures extract different types of features

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have a problem with the function bagoffeatures implemented in matlab computer vision system toolbox.

I'm doing a study of a classification of different types of images, first of all i'm trying to use bagoffeatures with diffenrets custom extractors, i want to divide my work in 2 branches, first extract SURFpoints and extract 3 different types of descriptors, for example SURF BRISK and FREAK, when i use in my custom extractor the next line:

```
features = extractFeatures(grayImage,multiscaleGridPoints,'Upright',true, 'method', 'SURF');
```

It allways need to get SURF method to work, but i need to be able to get differents types of descriptors.

Can i use the function bag of features from computer vision system toolbox to do this? or it only support surffeature extractions?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Is there something that is not clear on there?

Comment: yes, Read the documentation, and i tested the function and looked for a solution, i just want to know if someone knows if you can extract another type of descriptors.

Comment: You did not read it. Second line of the documentation: *bag = bagOfFeatures(imds,'CustomExtractor',extractorFcn) returns a bag of features that uses a custom feature extractor function to extract features from the output bag to learn its visual vocabulary. extractorFcn is a function handle to a custom feature extraction function.*

Comment: Sorry, I even made a custom extractor to try, using the example provide by matlab, probably i'm not explain my problem right for my english. When i make my extractor, i can use different functions to detect different type on keypoints, for example detectSurfFeatures or detectFASTfeatures, the problem is when i use the extractFeatures function, in this function you can extract 3 different types of descriptors, but it's failing when i don't use the method 'SURF', am i doing something wrong?

Comment: So your problem is with `extract Features` not `bagOfFeatures`? Still, the documentation says that you can not. What is unclear from that

Comment: So i can not use the bagoffeatures function to solve my problem? i will have to implement my own bag of words function, isn't it? sorry for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use BRISK or FREAK with MATLAB's implementation of bag-of-features, because the bag-of-features algorithm uses K-means clustering to create the "visual words". The problem is that BRISK and FREAK descriptors are binary bit strings, and you cannot cluster them with K-means, which only works on real-valued vectors.

You can certainly use different kinds of interest point detectors with the MATLAB's framework. However, you are limited to descriptors which are real-valued vectors.  So SURF and SIFT will work, but BRISK and FREAK will not. If you absolutely must use BRISK and FREAK, you will have implement your own bag of features. There are several methods for clustering binary descriptors, but I do not know how well any of them work in the context of bag-of-features.

Comment: Should i implement then my own bag of words to solve my problem? I really need to combine different types of detectors and extractors to classify my images with different methods

Comment: Thank you for the answer, well i don't need specially to use this 2 descriptors, but since i wanted to use computer vision toolbox I will try to do 2 type of tests: Get Fast keyPoints and use SURF, BRISK and FREAK descriptors, and the second one get SURF Keypoints and use SURF BRISK and FREAK descriptors. I will try to implement my own bag, thank you for your answer, appreciate it